# Internet connection as a hotspot

Tags: networking

My computer does not have a wired network connection, it only has a WiFi card.  In Windows 10 I can just click a button to turn my WiFi internet into a hotspot.  As far as I can tell this is about the only feature in Windows 10 that I like.  Can Ubuntu turn my WiFi connection into a hotspot?  I read that if I had a wired network connection I could but I could not find anything on a WiFi connection.  My laptop does not have a wired connection option at all that's why I'm wondering.  I might be trying to do something that's not even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hostapd

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd
```

create the file /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf with the follow content:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=my_ap
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=my_password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

then execute :

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```